# ASP.NET deployment - How to share BIN across multiple WebApp Projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7, shared-libraries

What is the best practice for sharing the assemblies of a bin folder across multiple ASP.net websites in IIS 7?

I've got several sites, each with slightly different HTML front ends, but all with the same middle tier logic and DB.  I don't want to redploy the same dlls to each of the many site's bin folders everytime I make a change.

Thanks.

Comment: You ask questions like you develop, it if doesn't work the first time, make an almost identical copy a day later and hope it works the second time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151453/shared-code-between-multiple-asp-net-projects.  If your first question didn't get the answer you wanted, reword the question and ask again.

Vote to close for duplication.

Comment: Scott, can you shoot me an email, I have the same issue aron (at) uswebpro (dot) com

Answer (score 3):

Yes, actually, you *do* want to deploy them individually. That's how it works.

If this truly offends you, then consider whether this common code should be in a WCF service called by all those sites.

Comment: hmm...ya, basically what I have is the same application branded differently across multiple cities...it seems quite redundant to put he exact same dlls inside a new web application for each one of these cities, when the only difference is the HTML views and the CSS.

Comment: As was suggested, you may want to make this one site, but adjust the branding based on the host header and/or user authentication.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to make your .Net code smart enough so that it can load the correct HTML front end based on the URL.  That way you could deploy your code to one location, then have multiple virtual directories use the same code.

Comment: That's not a bad idea David.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC, so I could just have different Views for each city, and have the city on the URL somewhere, and then I could have one webapp with one controller, just with front end logic to toggle the views.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try putting them in a common folder location and then change the assembly probing paths to look in that location.